# Run a Macro on a different sheet using VBA (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I want to make a sheet that has different macro-buttons This sheet is named **Buttons**. The macro-buttons in this sheet are linked to macros that should run on different sheets. I tried to make a macro-button for the sheet **1. Stock & Demand**:

```
Sub NeuerTag()

'Abfrage ob der Tag eingefügt werden soll, No = QUIT'
If MsgBox("Möchtest du die Tabelle vorbereiten?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Copies the last three coloumns of the Worksheet 1. Stock & Demand'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(Lastcol - 1).Resize(, 1).Select
Selection.Copy

'Selects the first empty cell in 1. Stock & Demand and pastes'
Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste

'Pastes the Today()'
Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = Date

'Paste Special - Values'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End With
End With

End Sub
```

Now I have a Problem. Every time I make a macro-button and let it run it only does his Job in the sheet **Buttons** and not in the sheet I want it to work.

I have to say I'm not really good at coding so please explain it to me like im five ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify worksheetname for the macro. For example you can try this:

```
 Workbooks("Your_worksheet_name_here").Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste
```

Normally, to keep things clear i do something like this:

```
 Set targetSheet = Workbooks("Your_worksheet_name_here").Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
 targetSheet.Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste
```

Comment: Do I have to use `Workbooks("Your_worksheet_name_here")`? It's the same workbook but a different sheet. `targetSheet.Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste` creates an error.

Comment: I misunderstood your problem,look at OldUgly's reply. I think his point aboud dots in code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Something minor - inside your `With` statements, you are mis-coding. Take notice of the ".". By misplacing / omitting it, you will end up with results in the incorrect tab.

For example

```
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
    Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

Should be

```
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
    Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

and this ...

```
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
    Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Columns(Lastcol - 1).Resize(, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy

'Selects the first empty cell in 1. Stock & Demand and pastes'
    Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste

'Pastes the Today()'
    Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Selection.Value = Date
```

should be ...

```
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
    Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Columns(Lastcol - 1).Resize(, 1).Copy

'Selects the first empty cell in 1. Stock & Demand and pastes'
    .Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste

'Pastes the Today()'
    .Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Date
```

Comment: Thank you! But now the row `'Selects the first empty cell in 1. Stock & Demand and pastes'
    .Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste` gives me an error.

Comment: `.Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight)` evaluates to cell `XFD3`, the last column in the worksheet. `.Offset(-2,1)` tries to go up two rows and to the right one row - right off the sheet. I don't know what you are trying to do - so I can't tell you a solution.

Comment: That what the macro should do but doesn't. Visual Basic shows me a yellow line :/. **Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this properly method.**

Comment: That's what the macro DOES do. You are trying to paste to a cell that doesn't exist, so it throws an error. The yellow line is just telling you where the error is.

Comment: But this macros does work on **1. Stock & Demand**. But doesn't when I let it run from a differen sheet. That's really confusing for me.

Comment: Where do you want to paste what you've copied?

Comment: I want that he goes to the end of the sheet and copies the last 3 columns. Then the macro should paste it to the first empty column and takes out the formulas from the previously copied three columns.

Comment: You need `PasteSpecial` rather than `Paste`.